# Docker accessible via localhost:8080 & 127.0.0.1:8080 but not via IP

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, docker, vagrant

I have the below scenario - 3x Vagrant VMs are spinned from the below Vagrantfile, up and running (visible within Oracle VirtualBox).

I am logged on docker1, the network type is "NAT", portforwarding is used (Guest:8080, Host:8080).

I am able to access the page from localhost:8080 & 127.0.0.1:8080 & 127.0.1.1:8080. However, I have no access via the IP (192.168.99.101:8080 is "Taking too long to respond" and can't be reached).

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.define "docker1" do |docker1|
        docker1.vm.box="xxx/centos-stream-8"
        docker1.vm.hostname = "docker1.do1.lab"
        docker1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.99.101"
        docker1.vm.provision "shell", path: "docker-setup.sh"
        docker1.vm.provision "shell", path: "other-steps.sh"
        docker1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1536"]
        end
    end
    
    config.vm.define "docker2" do |docker2|
        docker2.vm.box="xxx/centos-stream-8"
        docker2.vm.hostname = "docker2.do1.lab"
        docker2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.99.102"
        docker2.vm.provision "shell", path: "docker-setup.sh"
        docker2.vm.provision "shell", path: "other-steps.sh"
        docker2.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1536"]
        end
    end
    
    config.vm.define "docker3" do |docker3|
        docker3.vm.box="xxx/centos-stream-8"
        docker3.vm.hostname = "docker3.do1.lab"
        docker3.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.99.103"
        docker3.vm.provision "shell", path: "docker-setup.sh"
        docker3.vm.provision "shell", path: "other-steps.sh"
        docker3.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1536"]
        end
    end
end
```

the docker-setup.sh file is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "* Add Docker repository ..."
dnf config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

echo "* Install Docker ..."
dnf install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

echo "* Enable and start Docker ..."
systemctl enable docker
systemctl start docker

echo "* Add vagrant user to docker group ..."
usermod -aG docker vagrant
```

the other-steps.sh file is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "* Add hosts ..."
echo "192.168.99.101 docker1.do1.lab docker1" >> /etc/hosts
echo "192.168.99.102 docker2.do1.lab docker2" >> /etc/hosts
echo "192.168.99.103 docker3.do1.lab docker3" >> /etc/hosts

echo "* Install Additional Packages ..."
dnf install -y jq tree git nano

echo "* Firewall - swarm - open ports ..."
firewall-cmd --add-port=2377/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=4789/udp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=7946/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=7946/udp --permanent

echo "* Firewall - app - open port 8080 ..."
firewall-cmd --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

The networks are below:

```
[vagrant@docker1 etc]$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME              DRIVER    SCOPE
f2351cd29061   bridge            bridge    local
f91a21d83931   docker_gwbridge   bridge    local
c5fc9aedf330   host              host      local
oc2i4c2czira   ingress           overlay   swarm
50fe2b72573c   none              null      local
```

The etc/hosts content is here:

```
[vagrant@docker1 etc]$ cat hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.1.1 docker1.do1.lab docker1
192.168.99.101 docker1.do1.lab docker1
192.168.99.102 docker2.do1.lab docker2
192.168.99.103 docker3.do1.lab docker3
```

The command used to spin up a container is the below one:

```
docker container run -d --name web -p 8080:80 -e APP_MODE='test' swarm-app
```

I've researched tons of articles with the same issue but still cannot find a solution. I suppose this might have something to do with the DNS resolution of the IP address in question?

**Update: I am opening in CMD via curl the below addresses (Port Forwarding Host:8080, Guest:80), if there is any info to provide, please let me know:**
`[vagrant@docker1 ~]$ curl http:/localhost:8080 **-> does not open in browser**

#### Hello Docker Swarm!

Running in test mode.

---

*Served by: **be93b0268b1d***

[vagrant@docker1 ~]$ curl http://172.17.0.2:80 **-> this is the container IP - does not open through browser**

#### Hello Docker Swarm!

Running in test mode.

---

*Served by: **be93b0268b1d***

[vagrant@docker1 ~]$ curl http://192.168.99.101:8080 **-> this is the Docker host IP that is supposed to open through browser - as well without success**

#### Hello Docker Swarm!

Running in test mode.

---

*Served by: **be93b0268b1d***`

Comment: why not use nginx as reverse proxy?